# Obtaining effect size from "rstanarm" package's linear regression

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, rstan

In my study a *control group* (`c`) is pretested (`pre.c`) and post-tested (`pos.c`). Similarly a *treatment group* (`t`) is prettested (`pre.t`) and post-tested (`pos.t`). So I have two groups (`group factor`) tested at two time points (`time factor`).

I have fit a linear regression using `stan_glm()` from `rstanarm` package. I'm wondering though how to interpret the results without any effect sizes reported in the output (*see below*)?

Is it possible to obtain **effect sizes** for the *main* and *interaction* effects in `rstanarm` package?

```
pre.c = c(0.2521539, -0.8839510, 1.0106639, 1.2189900, -2.5187683, 0.1119494, 1.1506801, 1.2056992, 1.7262407, 3.1810580)
pos.c = c(1.5293298, 0.6043102, 0.5317992, 2.4416711, -2.6809858, 0.4981319, 4.0499866, 0.5683203, 4.0376835, 2.6794024)
pre.t = c(-1.0432592, 4.4818748, 3.5557269, 0.5164588, 3.3919210, 3.9045262, -0.6085360, 2.1122688, -0.2043023, 4.6272319)
pos.t = c(6.451760, 10.089001, 8.472512, 5.555241, 8.743465, 9.036619, 7.050737, 9.584346, 5.852163, 8.372967)

data <- data.frame(y = c(pre.c, pos.c, pre.t, pos.t), 
                time = rep(0:1, 20), 
               group = rep(c(0, 1), each = 20))

library(rstanarm) #### The R package ####
fit <- stan_glm(y ~ group * time, data = data, 
            prior_intercept = normal(0, 10), 
            prior = normal(0, 2.5),
            prior_aux = normal(0, 10))
```

**Output:**

```
    Estimates:
                mean   sd     2.5%   25%    50%    75%    97.5%
(Intercept)      0.9    0.9   -0.9    0.3    0.9    1.6    2.7 
group            3.2    1.3    0.6    2.4    3.2    4.0    5.7 
time             0.2    1.3   -2.3   -0.7    0.3    1.1    2.8 
group:time       1.4    1.8   -2.3    0.2    1.5    2.6    5.0 
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question 100% correctly, but I interpret it as the output from rstan being unfamiliar and that by "effect sizes", the answer that is sought is similar to the regression coefficients from a "traditional" frequentist analysis.

The effect sizes are displayed; when using a Bayesian analysis, you do not get a *single point estimate* for each effect size, but a posterior *distribution* of plausible effect sizes.

The posterior distribution is the "full" answer, as it includes the uncertainty of the parameter, but it is often summarised using simpler methods - e.g. the mean or median value is often used more or less similarly to the point estimate from frequentiest methods, and the 95% central values of the posterior distribution is used as a Bayesian *credible interval*, which is the Bayesian analogue of a frequentist 95% confidence interval

When you use a frequentist analysis (which are the statistical analysis most commonly used), you get a point estimate for each regression coefficient (= effect size) and a standard error that you can use to calculate a confidence interval for that effect size.
Fitting the same model using a frequentist methods leads to the following results:

```r
fit_freq <- glm(y ~ group * time, data = data)
summary(fit_freq)
```

An abbreviated output of the summary call above is included here:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   0.9089     0.8888   1.023   0.3133  
group         3.2573     1.2569   2.591   0.0137 *
time          0.2537     1.2569   0.202   0.8412  
group:time    1.4082     1.7776   0.792   0.4334
```

As you can see, for this simple model, the estimates from the frequentist analysis are very similar to the corresponding *mean* values from the posterior distribution from your Bayesian analysis above.

You can calculate the frequentist 95% confidence intervals using the estimates and standard errors:

```r
confint(fit_freq)
```

With output:

```
                 2.5 %   97.5 %
(Intercept) -0.8331139 2.650871
group        0.7937913 5.720889
time        -2.2098693 2.717229
group:time  -2.0758296 4.892139
```

This is once again very similar to the results from your Bayesian analysis; the standard distributions (SDs) from your Bayesian analysis are also almost identical to the standard errors frm the frequentist analysis.

The inclusion of the corresponding frequentist analysis here hopefully makes it easier to understand the interpretation; when using other models or priors that are more informative or not centered on 0, the results may differ substantially.
Remember that the entire posterior distribution from the Bayesian analysis is the answer; while a mean value of this distribution is a useful summary measure, it does not convey as much information.